CancellationToken in controller function of .Net Core suddenly becomes true
I just came into a very strange issue regarding cancellationToken. The web API is developed using .Net Core and frontend is in Angular. 1 hour ago I try to develop more feature and before starting I run it again and suddenly the cancellationToken becomes true. This never happens before. I made no changes in backend and frontend.
The controller function:
[HttpDelete("dqc")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteDQCAsync([FromBody] IEnumerable<DqcDto> dqcs, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await _managerService.DeleteDqcAsync(dqcs, cancellationToken);
        if (response)
        {
            return Ok(new { message = "DQC codes have been deleted successfully" });
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Delete selected DQC codes failed." });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

Even strange is, when I add breakpoint and debug the code, the function is invoked and cancellation is false. One second later the cancellationToken becomes true but I click nothing. Sometimes when I hit the button in the frontend, the function is even not invoked. Only when I add breakpoint in browser and execute line by line, the cancellationToken is always false.
It looks like that frontend sends the signal to cancel the request automatically but I have no idea why since this never happens even till this afternoon.
Could someone gives me a hint how I can figure out why this happens?
Update:
After hours of exploration, I find that the Angular code acts strangely. For example:
deleteItems(): void {
    let isDelete: boolean = false;
    const itemsToDelete = this.checkitems.map((item) => ({
      uicp: item.uicp,
      dqcCode: item.dqcCode,
      dqcDescription: item.dqcDescription,
      task: Object.keys(item.tasks)
        .filter((task) => item.tasks[task])
        .join(','),
      remark: item.remark,
      timestamp: item.lastUpdate,
    }));

    console.log(itemsToDelete);

    // Assuming there's a method in DataService to handle deletion
    this.dataService.deleteData(itemsToDelete).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('Items deleted:', response);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // Remove the deleted items from tableData
        this.tableData = this.tableData.filter(
          (item) => !this.checkitems.includes(item)
        );
        this.checkitems = [];
        isDelete = true;
      }
    });
    if (isDelete) {
      location.reload();
    }
  }

  saveItems(): void {
    let isAdd: boolean = false;
    let isUpdate: boolean = false;
    const newItems = this.checkitems
      .filter((item) => item.isNew)
      .map((item) => ({
        uicp: item.uicp,
        dqcCode: item.dqcCode,
        dqcDescription: item.dqcDescription,
        task: Object.keys(item.tasks)
          .filter((task) => item.tasks[task])
          .join(','),
        remark: item.remark,
      }));
    console.log('finish new items');

    const updatedItems = this.checkitems
      .filter((item) => !item.isNew)
      .map((item) => ({
        uicp: item.uicp,
        dqcCode: item.dqcCode,
        dqcDescription: item.dqcDescription,
        task: Object.keys(item.tasks)
          .filter((task) => item.tasks[task])
          .join(','),
        remark: item.remark,
        timestamp: item.lastUpdate,
      }));
    console.log('finish update item');

    console.log('New Items:', newItems);
    console.log('Updated Items:', updatedItems);
    if (newItems.length > 0) {
      console.log('start to add');
      this.dataService.addData(newItems).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log('wait for response');
          if (response.status === 200) {
            isAdd = true;
            console.log('New items added:', response.body);
          } else {
            console.error('Unexpected response:', response);
          }
          this.checkitems.forEach((item) => {
            item.isNew = false;
            item.selected = false;
          });
          this.checkitems = [];
          //this.updateSavedItems();
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.error('Error adding new items:', error.message);
        }
      );
    }

    if (updatedItems.length > 0) {
      console.log('start to update');
      this.dataService.updateData(updatedItems).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log('wait for response');
          if (response.status === 200) {
            isUpdate = true;
            console.log('Items updated:', response.body);
          } else {
            console.error('Unexpected response:', response);
          }
          this.checkitems.forEach((item) => {
            item.isNew = false;
            item.selected = false;
          });
          this.checkitems = [];
          //this.updateSavedItems();
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.error('Error updating items:', error.message);
        }
      );
    }
    if (isAdd || isUpdate) {
      location.reload();
    }
  }

Service functions:
deleteData(items: any[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.apiUrl}/dqc`, {'body':items});
  }

  addData(newItems: any[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/dqc`, newItems);
  }

   updateData(updatedItems: any[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/dqc`, updatedItems);
  } 

There are two main functions, one is to delete items and another one is to update or/and add items. In these two functions, somehow the program skip the middle part and directly jumps to the end to refresh the page, even skip the parts that send requests to backend. That causes the cancellationToken set to true. Sometimes this issue disappears and everything goes well. It acts like that the location.reload() is magnet and leads the program to execute this line first.
Does someone know why this happens?

Maybe a request timeout send by the FE because of the debugging session?

@decius Could you please tell me how to check?

You could open the DEV Tools in your browser with F12. There you can see the cancellation. Set a Breakpoint. And wait 120 seconds after the breakpoint was hit. I think this should trigger the cancellation.

@decius I found how it happens but I have no idea why. At the end of the Delete function in Angular I refresh the page using location.reload() But somehow the program skips function to send request but directly refresh the page. In this case a cancellation request is sent. I do not know why this happens

Can you add this code to your question. If you are not awaiting the first call to your API this can happen as well I could imagine.

@decius I have added the code in Update.

I´ve posted an answer. The reason why this is happening is clear to me. check it out.

The problem is, that location.reload() is directly executed after subscibe(). It runs in parallel - the call to your API is not awaited that way. Thats the reason for the cancellation. You have to put the location.reload() statement into the subscribe() like that:
this.dataService.deleteData(itemsToDelete).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('Items deleted:', response);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // Remove the deleted items from tableData
        this.tableData = this.tableData.filter(
          (item) => !this.checkitems.includes(item)
        );
        this.checkitems = [];
        location.reload();
      }
    });
  }

And by the way: Instead of using location.reload() you should just call your GET action of this API, when the delete call is finished.

This is not the cause. isAdd and isUpdate are false. They are set to true only after the response is received. You are right about the location.reload that is outside, but it doesn't execute because both conditions are false.

I was not talking about update or saveItems. The initial question was about the delete method. And there is clearly the reason, that the reload is outside of the subscribe. There are no isAdd or isUpdate flags. So, I answered the initial question before editing the post. I don´t see a reason to down vote it.

There might be other problems in the other methods. Than write a second answer and talk about that, instead of down voting my answer.

It is the same idea for delete. isDelete is true only after the response and is always false when  location.reload(); is reached.

What is causing the cancellation then? It is also not your boolean flags. The code was wrong on the reload part. And this answer is correct. I didn´t hear an answer from you.

I don't know what is the problem about  cancellationToken, but your explanation is wrong and u being a smart guy, understand that flag is false at that time and the reload is not invoked. U are an cloud architect so it should make sense for u.

The position of all the ifs are also wrong. That is what I pointed out. With my solution you do not need these flags anymore. That might not solve the whole problem, but is a first step in the right direction. Your behaviour is not constructive from my point of view.

@decius Your solution helps to solve the issue to avoid setting the cancellationToken is true, so I mark it useful. But I really don't understand why location.relocate() is executed before other code even it is on the last line. Even if the response code is not executed. Aslo I find the issue about my functions sending requests to backend. I should use Observable<HttpResponse<string>> and add specify the responseType, otherwise the returned response has no Status property. I don't know why but this also helps avoid errors.

Thats hard to tell from these lines of code. But, as I mentioned, remove all the bool flags and put the reload inside the subscribe() function and then check again. Or even better: Instead of reload() it, execute a GET call to your API to get the new data. If you would use RxJS for example it would be even easier to work with these Obserables, because then you can chain the different calls one after another.

@decius Thanks for the tips. I am new to Angular so I am developing while learning. I will note this. Thank you again.

You´re welcome. Of course you are learning. thats fine. did the removal of the bools and putting reload to the right place fix your problem?

@decius yes it did. But I just don't know why this line gets executed in advance.

Because of the if-statements it actually shouldn´t be executed. But to use these if statement is also a bad practise, because of some concurrency issues together with your debugging it can lead to execution in an other order. The main take away is, that your delete call and the reload() call (without the ifs) are executed in parallel, so at the same time, because subscribe() will not wait until the operation inside (your delete call) is finished.

If its clearer now and my answer helped to solve the problem, feel free to accept the answer as well. Thx. :)
